# Difference between MAD function and manual MAD computation in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a large dataset `data` with many non-numeric columns `x1, x2, ... x30`, and a numeric column `y`.

I would like to compute a mean absolute deviation (MAD) for `y` per different `x1` and `x2` combinations.

Say, for `x1 == 'A'` and `x2 == 'B'`, I want to compute MAD for `y`. I did:

```
data %>%
   group_by(x1, x2) %>%
   filter(x1 == "A", x2 == "B") %>%
   summarise(mad = mad(y, center = mean(y)))
```

However, when I compute it manually, it returns a different value:

```
data %>%
   group_by(x1, x2) %>%
   filter(x1 == "A", x2 == "B") %>%
   summarise(manual_mad = sum(abs(y - mean(y)))/n())
```

Which one is a correct computation, and how should I tweak one or another to have the same value?

Comment: @Maël whoops, thanks. I did put `center` in my real code though.

Comment: Your manual calculation looks right mo me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of `?mad`:

> The actual value calculated is constant * cMedian(abs(x - center)).

Indeed, with 1.4826 being the default `constant` value, we get the same result manually:

```r
y = 1:10
mad(y, center = mean(y))
#[1] 3.7065

1.4826 * median(abs(y - mean(y)))
#[1] 3.7065
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are looking for the **mean** absolute deviation, which is defined<sup>[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/247821)</sup> as:

> MAD = Σ(|x_i - μ|)/n

```
mnad <- \(x, ...) mean(abs(x - mean(x, ...)), ...)

mnad(1:9)
# [1] 2.222222
```

The `mad()` function calculates the **median** absolute deviation.

Comment: Shouldn't it still return the same value if I put `mad(y, center = mean(y))`?

Comment: @jstaxlin Type `mad` in the console (without parentheses) and examine the source code of `mad()`.